# R: Installing package from Github on company network

Tags: r, rstudio, geocoding

I would like to install and load [this](https://github.com/rCarto/photon) package from GitHub on my company laptop with a company network.

I have been facing issues with the two following possible solutions:

- When I download the zip and install it through RStudio>Tools>Install Packages>Install from: Package Archive File (.zip; tar.gz), it seems that the package is well installed. However, I have difficulties loading the package through `library(photon-master)`. It tells me that package must be of length 1.
- When I try to install the package from GitHub, I also have some difficulties when I use the following code:

  ```
  require(devtools)  
  require(httr)
  set_config(use_proxy(url="userproxy.xxx.xxx.local", port=8080, username="IDxxxxxx",password="xxx"))
  devtools::install_github(repo = 'rCarto/photon')
  ```

  where the proxy server settings have been found in

> Start>control panel>Network and Internet > click on Internet Options >
>   click on connections tab then right at the bottom click on LAN
>   settings > Check Proxy Server Settings

I get the following error message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) :
>   Failure when receiving data from the peer

Any solution would be greatly appreciated. I just want to use the package.
Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: When you download the zip and install it that way does `library(photon)` work?

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't work. R tells me that there is no package called photon. I have tried many combinations, but none of them work

Comment: download the source and install locally, also, should be `library(photon)`

Comment: That means you can not install from the "package pane" -> install button in RStudio?

Comment: Actually I manage to install it (Installing package into ‘C:/Users/IDxxxxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’). However, I have difficulties loading it using library().

Comment: In my experience, installing packages through a company proxy can be next to impossible. Does the proxy work with a different package?  Can you install at home, or in a coffee shop, or by using your phone as a hot-spot? Can you install a package from Cran via the proxy?